# Darktable doesn't recognize Intel Graphics 620's OpenCL (beignet) in Fedora 27

Tags: fedora, intel-graphics

I am writing this question since I had no problem in years of using OpenCL with nVidia graphics in fedora and testing Darktable with it. But now in Fedora 27 I am trying to use Darktable with Intel Graphics opencl capability but when I do `darktable -d opencl` I get this response as it doesn't recognize:

```
Beignet: self-test failed: (3, 7, 5) + (5, 7, 3) returned (6, 7, 5)
```

and when I do `clifo` it winds three devices. I thought it should find only two, my CPU and my GPU. My CPU is `Intel Core i7-7500U` and that's it.

I have installed these packages: `ocl-icd`, `opencl-filesystem`, `opencl-utils-devel` and `beignet`. I think these cover all the necessary dependencies.

The question is: Is it possible to use Darktable's opencl capability with this GPU or not? and how can I do it using beignet and Fedora 27?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug with __local memory on beignet, see if this workaround works for you:

```
export OCL_IGNORE_SELF_TEST=1
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but unfortunately It doesn't fix the problem. Although it seems like the solution, I get the response which says:

Intel(R) HD Graphics Kabylake ULT GT2' because the driver `OpenCL 2.0 beignet 1.3' is blacklisted.

Answer (score 0):

Beignet is blacklisted in darktable. You could try to remove it from the list and recompile darktable and see if it works: https://github.com/darktable-org/darktable/blob/master/src/common/opencl_drivers_blacklist.h Line 27.
Darktable devs have disabled Beignet because they see not much gain in using intel cards with opencl. You can read more about it here: https://www.darktable.org/2012/03/darktable-and-opencl/